# Monitor any other running app from a service Android

Tags: android, service

I was developing an app for an enterprise which has given the employees an android phone, they wanna monitor every time a user tries to open any other app and send a report to a manager so I´ve developed an android service that checks every time any other app is call meaning: OnCreate, onResume, etc.(that´s done) Now they wanna check what that particular user did once he got into the other app: for example if he opened the messages(com.android.mms) , what message he sent or what he had recieve. other example: if he opened the dialer(com.android.dialer) they wanna know what phone he called. What makes it tricky for me, is that they want this for EVERY POSSIBLE APP a user can have installed in their phone.

My Question is the following: is there a way to capture this kind of information of a running app, from a service?

I appreciate any answer and I´m open to suggestions of how should i do this.

Comment: In short, not possible. You can only get the list of currently running apps not what is happening inside app itself.

Comment: who are these people, and what year do they live in?